# Best practices for an images-only navbar with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create a navbar with a `ul` element in which each item on the navbar is a textless, image-only link. So I set it up like so:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="./"></a></li>
</ul>
```

And then I realized I didn't really know how to get the images in there. I thought of two ideas, but they each have problems:

- Put an `img` tag inside the anchor. This isn't good content/design separation, and also, if I want to make the image change when the user hovers over it (which I do), it gets a lot more complicated.
- Use CSS background images, but now I have to give the anchor a width and height equal to the image's dimensions, forcing me to modify my code every time I change the images.

Image-only navbars are very common, so is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: I'm using css styling, it is clean,better for performance - if these are images that are part of design, not changing dynamically of course

Comment: If image-only navbars are so common, like you say, what do most of them do? Use inspector and see how they're doing it. I'd use css, if I had to do this.

Comment: You don't want to add img tag, you don't want use background-images, you don't want to give width, height !! nothing left buddy..! other than font-icons !! Now, even i'm curious, what will you do

Comment: As far as I can tell they "were" common. Like 10 Years ago :) Try styling as much as possible with css, as long as you're not overcomplicate everything

Answer (score 0):

Use both, use image with transparency and bacground-image, so you can change img on hover and transparent img will stretch `<a>` tag for you:

```
<a><img src="some-image.jpg" /></a>
```

and css something like this:

```
a img{
   opacity:0;
}
a{
   background-image:url(some-image.jpg);
}
a:hover{
   background-image:url(some-other-image.jpg);
}
```

Comment: `-someprefix-` isn't necessary. Only IE8 doesn't support opacity, but you can mimic it's behaviour with `filter`. But come on, we ain't gonna support IE8 anymore, do we ;) Furthermore; if you set the opacity of an element to 0, the background image will not be visible as well. So you'll have to stack some elements to achieve the effect as you are trying to build it now.

Comment: @giorgio yes, prefixes are not necessary, they are optional, thats why i dont bother to write them. Opacity: check code one more time, `opacity` is set on `img` but `background-image` is set on `a` tag(parent) therefore is not afected

Comment: Ah sorry, you're right, my last comment can be ignored ;) But I still stand on the -prefix- part, because there isn't even a opacity prefix... see also [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-opacity) (although maybe there was on a reaaaaally old firefox version that no-one uses anymore ;))

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it these way:

**CSS**

```
ul{
    display:inline-block;
    width:350px;
    height:150px;
}
ul li{
    display:block;
}
ul li a, ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
ul li.fb a{
    background:url(http://placehold.it/350x150) no-repeat left center;
}
ul li.tw a{
    background:url(http://placehold.it/350x150) no-repeat left center;
}

<ul>
    <li class="fb"><a href="http://facebook.com"></a></li>
    <li class="tw"><a href="http://twitter.com"></a></li>   
</ul>
```

And you can put all these images in sprite, etc...

http://jsfiddle.net/sthAngels/842d4493/

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way to achieve this is to insert the on-hover-image (which will of course have the same dimensions as the normal image) in the anchor itself, and stack an element on top of it, which will have the 'normal-state' image as a background. Then on hover, hide the stacked element to show the on-hover-image. The anchor itself will now by itself have the images dimension, as will the stacked element.

html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href class="link1"><img src="link1-hover-image.png"><span></span></a></li>
    <li><a href class="link2"><img src="link2-hover-image.png"><span></span></a></li>
    <li><a href class="link3"><img src="link3-hover-image.png"><span></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
a { position: relative; }
a img { vertical-align: bottom; } /* little hack for correct placement */
a span { display: block; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; }
a:hover span { opacity: 0; }

.link1 span { background-image: url(link-1-image.png); }
.link2 span { background-image: url(link-2-image.png); }
.link3 span { background-image: url(link-3-image.png); }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3jun6k1m/)

**But** like everyone said; wherever possible just use plain css. Much faster, easier to maintain. So only use this if it's reaaally not possible to use css to style your buttons.